# Как создать файл фиксированного размера?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Как создать файл фиксированного размера, например, 1 мегабайт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать при помощи `fsutil` , однако, потребуются права администратора:

```
fsutil file createnew file.bin 1048576
```

Answer (score 1):

Если без прав админа, то можно используя временные файлы, очередью команд:

```
cmd /c @echo ab>a.txt&del b.txt /f& @for /l %a in (1,1,9) do (@copy /b a.txt+a.txt b.txt&@copy /b b.txt+b.txt a.txt) & del b.txt /f
```

Comment: Логично, что после этих команд получится файл a.txt объемом 1 русский мегайбайт или мебибайт (кому как удобнее). Но не 1000000 байт.